# Fullscreen WebView in Android studio

Tags: webview, android-webview

I want to use webview in android studio , but when I use it the Screen seems that has padding but I don't have any Padding .
I really appreciate anyone can help me to solve this simple problem

[my_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1LaB.jpg)
I used the xml code below but it didn't get any result

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        tools:context=".activities.WebPageActivity" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp" />
     </RelativeLayout>
```